# Fractional scaling flameshot screenshot problem 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04

I have 2 monitors: one 2560x1440 and one 1920x1080.
The 2560 one is at 125% scaling, the other one at 100%.
I've set up flameshot as my screenshot software.
When I try to make a screenshot, the first time I try my screens start turning on and off again as long as the screenshot software is active.
When I try a second time, my screens don't flicker on and off anymore, but then I can only make a screenshot of the top left part of my monitor. Does anyone have a clue what causes this behaviour, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Github issue for your problem:
https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/564

There are 2 comments which propose a usable solution:

wzzyj commented on Oct 21, 2021

> Enable DPI awareness will fix the issue.
>
> Short story version: Try to start it following command:
> `env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 flameshot`
> If it works we can "persist" it by adding the env variable to .profile
> `echo "export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1" >> ~/.profile`
> Long story:
> version debug (in Chinese):
> https://blog.willzhou.com/solve-fractional-scaling-issue-for-flameshot/

attiks commented on Dec 2, 2021

> I'm using the following on Ubuntu 20, primary screen set to 100%,
> external screen set to 150% scaling
>
> `export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`
> `export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS="1;1.5"`
> works like a charm

The first one works for me. I didn't test the second though.

Answer (score 4):

This one is the one working for me.

`QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0  QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS="1;1" flameshot`

If I play around with the factors (wich I have as 1.75 and 1) it shrinks the 2 monitors when taking the screenshot, which is weird and very small to see correctly. (check image below, the 2 monitors view are compressed) but proposed command works like a charm.

[image: How the capture looks when using factor]

Answer (score 0):

Set the refresh rate to 60Hz in Display Settings

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me